# To what extent I am free with my voting?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

To what extent I am free with my voting?  And - especially - with downvoting.

I came into argument with another user on the reasons for the voting. So, I decided to ask.

Beside usual awful no-research-effort questions and quick-and-wrong answers, I am often voted down for the answers you would call *correct* ones:

- When I think there shouldn't be answer at all (helping the OP to shoot himself in the foot or feeding a help vampire)
- To negate an over-upvoting craze for the silly answer on even more silly question.

So, the question is - what you think on these reasons?

And - bonus question - is there any difference in the policies for the voting up and down?

Comment: Sounds perfectly ok to me, you're free to vote as you please. There'll always be people who don't like it

Comment: And people wonder why voting is anonymous...

Comment: Unless and until you're not trying to game the system(either by using sock puppets or using it to take revenge), Voting is absolutely your choice and nobody can stop you from doing the same.

Comment: You are not only free **with** your voting. You are free **because** of your voting. Democracy FTW!

Answer (score 15):

Honestly, there are no hard and fast rules on voting other than

1. you don't weaponize them for or against users, also known as targeted voting, and
2. you don't cheat by engaging dummy accounts or sock puppets to vote.

Other than that, really, you can vote however you like, this applies both to upvotes and downvotes, even if people may not agree with those votes. Just remember that there are certain reasons to vote that make more sense than others. For example, it's not a terribly good idea to upvote spam, or downvote a question/answer just because you don't like the technology it's about or makes use of.

Personally I would abstain from voting on a question even if it's asked by a help vampire, unless the question really is that awful (which, then again, is true of most questions asked by help vampires *anyway*). And trying to downvote to counter an excessive number of upvotes, while noble, is in most cases only going to cause unnecessary strife ("whoever did that, if you think a measly -2 is going to get to me you're sorely deluded). In my opinion, you'd certainly be better off expending that downvote on something that truly is awful.

Comment: I edited your post (which I assume you noticed as you edited it afterwards), but I believe you aren't supposed to use sock puppets to vote on friends or associates either, so I removed the 'on your own posts' portion there. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @jmac: You are absolutely right - any form of targeted voting (which was the correction I made) whether using your own account or with socks is not OK.

Answer (score 11):

First, voting and reputation are not equivalent. An up vote and a down vote, while they counteract the score on the post, do not in fact counter the reputation awarded to a user. When people vote with the intention of simply negate another vote, it creates an imbalance in reputation. Ideally, you should be voting on posts because they're either helpful or not helpful, not because you feel sorry for a user or because you feel they've been over-awarded. While no one can control how you vote, and as Pekka says, "you're free to vote as you please", these guidelines help ensure that posts are scored based on how useful they really are as a resource of knowledge, which is the real reason Stack Exchange sites exist.

Second, there's not really any difference in policies for up voting or down voting, but it's worth mentioning that votes ideally shouldn't be applied to a person but should target that person's content. Again, no one can control how you vote, but these are how the founders visualized how voting should work.

Comment: Good point about imbalance when voting to negate some other effect.

Comment: This *is* the point. A quick answer on the proper syntax fix, for the question that has been asked zillion times already, easily gets 8. While really *useful* answer for the question that require more knowledge than usual participant has, scarcely gets 1. I have really disagree with your measure for helpfulness.

Comment: Thing is, I never defined helpfulness, and it sounds like there's more to the question than you're actually letting on. This is why context is important in these discussions, as I'm not really sure what you're getting at.